# Is there a word for a role that can only be held by one person in a group at a time?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'm looking for a word that describes a role that can only be held by one person within a network or group at any one time.

For example, with a role like 'king' - there can only be one king of a particular nation at any one time. If another person wants to claim the role of king - they'd have to displace the existing king.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Lots of position titles imply a single person. Captain, Chair, Leader, etc. Then somebody comes along and adds "Co-" to it. And you get "Co-Captain" etc.   Heh heh. What's the opposite of a double superlative?

Comment: A ["Highlander"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander_(film)) role?

Comment: How about a unique role? I was taught that unique is an absolute concept. It cannot ne qualified, you cannot be more / almost etc unique.  You are either unique or you are not.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an **exclusive role**, a **singleton role** or just a **singleton**.

> [exclusive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exclusive): single, sole

> [singleton](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/singleton): an individual member or thing distinct from others grouped
> with it

Comment: IMO singleton is mostly used in card games. [Exclusive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exclusive) is better.

Comment: @WeatherVane And also computer programming :) So I thought maybe it could be introduced into other contexts...

Answer (score 0):

Solo, solitary, lone

**Solo** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/solo)) A job or performance done by one person alone. "solo accountancy", "sole accountant". **Sole** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sole)) Only.

**Solitary** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/solitary))  Performed, passed, or endured alone. Single; individual; sole.

**Lone** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lone)) Solitary; having no companion. Isolated or lonely; lacking companionship. Sole; being the only one of a type.